# OpenGL translating up when it shouldn't

Tags: opengl

I have a skybox and some water with a waving effect. The skybox and water move as the camera moves. This is all well and good, but when I press space, I want the camera to move up, but without the skybox or water moving up too. The skybox doesn't move, but the water comes up  as well as the camera, which I dont want. Anyone know why?

```
//Camera
        glRotatef(elevation, 1,0,0);
        glRotatef(heading, 0,1,0);
        glRotatef(rot, 0,0,1);
        glTranslatef(-eyeX,-eyeY,-eyeZ);

        //Skybox
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(eyeX,0,eyeZ);  
            drawCube();
            drawSea();
        glPopMatrix();
```

None of the translate variables are being used in `drawSea()`.

Comment: I believe it's the right time to learn about scene management

Comment: It would help to provide us with more of the relevant code, without knowing what is going on in drawSea() and drawCube(), there's only so much we can ascertain

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a skybox you should not try to "compensate" the camera. It's far easier to reset the modelview matrix to identity and then just apply only the camera rotation. As it happens this is done by simply taking the modelview matrix and clearing the last column and last row to [0,0,0,1].